# Android data persistence, web services and redundancies

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, android-sqlite

I'm working on an Android application that will present data provided by an external JSON web service over the internet (The web service server has access to a MySQL database over its network).

The data must be available in the application during offline mode so it will have to be persisted on the application side somehow. I'd be very interested in learning best practices for such an approach.

Currently, I'm thinking about utilizing an SQLite database on the application side that innevitably (?) needs to look relatively identical to the MySQL database accessed by the web service.

This feels very redundant and clumsy to me, however, my experience is very limited and I would love to hear from people who have more experience with this approach on how to proceed.

I'm also curious to know best practices regarding how much logic should exist on the application side versus through the web service interface. Shouldn't most of the logic be programmed on the web service side and then the application's responsibility is only about data presentation?

I am eager to learn and prefer to spend more time on something than needed if it means it will be easier to maintain in the long run.

If anything is unclear please let me know. Thanks for any feedback :)

Comment: sqlite is not a bad option. All of your other questions would require us to know more about your specific application than you've chosen to share.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Using SQLite is probably the way to go either way for presisting data, but to what degree should it resemble the "big" MySQL database accessed by the web service? Isn't it bad practice to have two relatively identical databases?